# Mongodb - Unable to drop database

Tags: mongodb

I cannot drop the database crunchbase in my mongodb. After I run db.dropDatabase() the console displays ok but the crunchbase still in mongodb. Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possibly permissions, but interesting that it is not shown as an error. If something were actually "dropped" then the response would be `{ "dropped": "crunchbase", "ok": 1 }` which this does not. Which mongodb version is this? FYI please post "text" instead of screenshots in the future.

Comment: Thanks I am using version 3.2.4

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a database called "cruchbase" (no "n" in crunch). The "crunchbase" database was dropped. You just have to go in and drop the "cruchbase" database as well.